# Rust script to generate JavaScript asset list file based on directory contents

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. I wanted to create a script to read the contents on a directory, and then generate a js file exporting this assets. I wrote this code, it works but I'm not totally happy with it. I want to know the best way to do this.

you can check full code here: https://gist.github.com/JoseLuna12/0e576081761fa0594471fdb15ee3d038

````
    let r_files = ReadFiles::new(public_path);
    let file_names = r_files.file_names();

    let mut file_content = "".to_owned();
    let mut variable_names = "".to_owned();
    for f in file_names {
        let v_name: Vec<&str> = f.split(".").collect();

        let content = vec![
            "import".to_owned(),
            ["'".to_owned(), v_name[0].to_owned(), "'".to_owned()].join(""),
            "from".to_owned(),
            ["'".to_owned(), f.to_owned(), "'".to_owned()].join(""),
            "\r\n".to_owned(),
        ];
        file_content.push_str(&content.join(" "));
        variable_names.push_str(v_name[0]);
        variable_names.push_str(",\r\n")
    }

    let export_values = vec!["export {\r\n", &variable_names, "}"].join("");

    let final_file = [file_content, export_values].join("");

    fs::write("utils.js", &final_file);```
````

Comment: Since your full code is not long, consider including the full code to provide more context.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Like @l-f said, please include more context for your question - also the link to the full code doesn't work, otherwise I'd have to that for you now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build strings in rust, use `format!()` or `write!()`

```
let content = vec![
        "import".to_owned(),
        ["'".to_owned(), v_name[0].to_owned(), "'".to_owned()].join(""),
        "from".to_owned(),
        ["'".to_owned(), f.to_owned(), "'".to_owned()].join(""),
        "\r\n".to_owned(),
    ];
file_content.push_str(&content.join(" "));
```

Can be:

```
 let content = format!("import '{}' from '{}'\r\n", v_name[0], f);
 file_content.push_str(&format!("import '{}' from '{}'\r\n", v_name[0], f));
```

Or even:

```
 write!(file_content, "import '{}' from '{}'\r\n", v_name[0], f)?;
```

This is much simpler and more efficient then what you are doing because it builds less intermediate strings.

```
let r_files = ReadFiles::new(public_path);
```

I don't know what this ReadFiles is, but it seems like it could readily replaced with the builtin `std::fs::readdir`.

```
    let v_name: Vec<&str> = f.split(".").collect();
```

If you use the standard `std::path::PathBuf`, instead of strings you can use the `file_stem` method instead of this.